# Node request output differing from curl output

Tags: node.js, curl, node-request

I'm able to make a request using curl, get the response and parse it into protobuf. However, on trying to do the same with node's `request`, I'm unable to parse the `body` argument into protobuf, even when I've converted it into a buffer.

Here's the hex dump of what the request should have output

```
00000000: 1088 8080 80f0 fca4 f02c a206 00a2 0600  .........,......
00000010: a206 5408 a7b5 a9a4 e22a 10ff 8ac8 b9e3  ..T......*......
00000020: 2a1a 121a 100a 0e09 2130 0000 0000 0000  *.......!0......
00000030: 107b 18d4 011a 121a 100a 0e09 2130 0000  .{..........!0..
00000040: 0000 0000 107b 18d4 011a 121a 100a 0e09  .....{..........
00000050: 2130 0000 0000 0000 107b 18d4 011a 081a  !0.......{......
00000060: 0612 0408 0110 15a2 0600 a206 00         .............
```

This is what dumping the created buffer onto disk and using `xxd` to dump it into hex

```
00000000: 10ef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd  ................
00000010: efbf bdef bfbd efbf bd2c efbf bd06 00ef  .........,......
00000020: bfbd 0600 efbf bd06 5408 efbf bdef bfbd  ........T.......
00000030: efbf bdef bfbd efbf bd2a 10ef bfbd efbf  .........*......
00000040: bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 2a1a 121a 100a  ..........*.....
00000050: 0e09 2130 0000 0000 0000 107b 18ef bfbd  ..!0.......{....
00000060: 011a 121a 100a 0e09 2130 0000 0000 0000  ........!0......
00000070: 107b 18ef bfbd 011a 121a 100a 0e09 2130  .{............!0
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 107b 18ef bfbd 011a 081a  .......{........
00000090: 0612 0408 0110 15ef bfbd 0600 efbf bd06  ................
```

There might be a small difference due to change in timestamps (my server sends that back within the protobuf), but both of the files should have been parsable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so `request` assumes your response to be a unicode string, strips non-unicode characters and mutilates it unless you add `encoding: null`
 to `requestSettings`.

Adding the said param to the settings fixes it.